# android layout with selector as a background, and overlapping text view

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to draw a button using a "drawable/selector" so that the background color changes as the button is clicked.
So I defined the background of my RelativeLayout using the drawable (that has the selector). This first step works fine: when i click the layout object, the color changes.

In that RelativeLayout, I now add two independant dynamic Text Views. These Text Views are now using much of the space of the RelativeLayout. So when I click on the text views object, the background of the parent layout does not change anymore.

So, is there a way to have a layout with a dynamic background (to handle user's clicks so it changes color) and have overlapping views on the top?

Note that the background of the relativeLayout is a gradient that goes from top to bottom.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/titleBackground"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/light_text"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/light_text_alpha"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="@dimen/secondarylisttext_size"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your textview are capturing the click events and they are not passed to the relativelayout in the background. You will need to add a onTouchListener to both textviews and set the background for the relative layout inside the touch listener based on 'ACTION_DOWN,ACTION_UP' of the motion event.

There might be ways to make the textview pass the click events. But Im not sure about it. The above method is just 1 solution. There can be others.

Answer (score 0):

As blessenm said, everything depends on the TextView, if you make them clickable then the parent selector doesn't count anymore (of course you can use a selector also on the TextView).